# Saved Imorts in Access Db that is deployed (copied) to another machine

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, odbc, ms-access-2010

Suppose you've created an Access Db file where you've imported some database tables from a remote SQL server on a network. You then saved that import process in Access that is available by clicking on the `Saved Imports` button on the `External Data` tab on the `Access Ribbon`. Now you send that Access file to someone on the same network who does not either know or does not have permissions to create an ODBC dsn on his machine.

**Question**:

1. Is there any place in that Access file where you can change the DSN settings to match the configuration on the destination machine?
2. Is there any other way that person can run that Saved Imports from the Access file that you sent to that person?

Comment: end user must have same odbc driver installed.. use DNS less connection method. aka refreshing linked tables manually in tableDefs

Comment: @krishKM Thank you for trying to help. DSN less connection requires programming. Is there a work around w/o programming? And if user has the same ODBC drives installed and a DSN created for the user with same configuration, will the same Access file (with `Saved Imports`) work?